# Titanium thinks I have 3.1.2 but I installed 3.4.1. What to do?

Tags: macos, titanium, titanium-mobile

I opened Titanium after about a year without using it. I upgraded everything before doing anything but now everything crashes.

Here is what I have:

Under titanium studio I am able to set the SDK to `3.4.1`, but when I try to create a project I get:

```
[31m Command "create" incompatible with this version of the Titanium CLI[39m
[WARN] :   Requires version >=3.2.1, currently 3.1.2
```

So then I went to terminal and run

```
titanium -v
```

and I get

```
3.1.2
```

I tried

```
sudo npm install -g titanium
```

But it doesn't seem to do nothing.
I also tried to uninstall Titanium with

```
sudo npm -g uninstall titanium
```

but I get

```
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules: "titnaium"
```

When I run

```
type -a titanium
```

I get

```
titanium is /usr/local/bin/titanium
```

I also tried restarting my computer, opening and closing Studio, etc...but I am totally lost, for some reason I can't make it work.
Any idea on how to solve this will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Just to be fair, you tried to uninstall tit**na**ium not titanium.

Comment: It was a typo in the error message too. I suspect the typo was there in the actual command you tried to run.

Comment: Trust me, I would be very happy if that typo was the solution, but still `titanium -v` gives me `3.1.2`. Any help?

Comment: Could you paste somewhere the output of sudo npm install -g titanium?

Comment: @maxdangelo I have just found the solution and it was indeed in the output of npm install -g titanium . The first 2 lines show the paths titanium is expecting and in my case they were not in my PATH variable. So I simply added them and it seems to be working now. If you want to put that into an answer I can mark it as solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all run following command in CLI

```
ti sdk select
```

Select the 3.4.1 as your sdk and let me know if that solved the problem

Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks, I did that and I got `Titanium SDK version to activate (3.4.1.GA)`  but when I run `titanium -v` after that I get `3.1.2`

Comment: maybe this helps, when I do `ti info` I get `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/longjohn/dist/longjohn.js:181
        throw e;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'join' of undefined`

Comment: Yes, this is too weird because when I do a `sudo titanium create` I get

`Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.2, Titanium SDK version 3.4.1.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/

[ERROR] Command "create" incompatible with this version of the Titanium CLI
[WARN]  Requires version >=3.2.1, currently 3.1.2
[ERROR] Unable to find command "create"`

But I can't seem to be able to update CLI or Titanium is using the CLI from some other location I can't find

Comment: Delete the old titanium studio and install again i think it would automatically work this is a little bit weird solution but should work

Comment: I just have one Titanium Studio under /applications, I think I already did that but I will try one more time and let you know how it goes.Thanks

Comment: Also I noticed that even if I delete Titanium Studio from /Applications when I go to terminal and type titanium -v I get 3.1.2 is that normal? Shouldn't it throw me an error instead?

Comment: hmm cant say about that